# Telerik MVC: Telerik Menu Drops down Under Telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, menu, grid, telerik

I have just added a Telerik menu to my MVC application.  I also have many views that render Telerik grids on them.

Problem:  My menu has one item with sub items.  When I hover over that menu item, the dropdown slides beneath the Telerik Grid, which hides most of the sub items and makes it impossible to click them.  Any idea how to make the menu dropdown slide over the grid instead of under it?

[alt text http://www.slickappstest.info/telerik_menu.gif](http://www.slickappstest.info/telerik_menu.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this has something to do with the z-index of the menu. Try increasing it gradually (compared to the grid) until it displays over the grid table. Hope this helps.

Dick

Answer (score 1):

in **telerik.common.min.css** delete the **overflow:hidden;** rule for selector **.t-grid td** so that it reads :

```
.t-grid td
{
vertical-align:middle;
line-height:1.6em;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
border-style:solid;
border-width:0 1px 0 0;
padding:.25em .6em;
}
```

the result will be :

[image]

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but wouldn't it be better to override it in a later-included file?  That way you don't lose your edit when you upgrade to newer telerik versions.